# How to reload the USB disk in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, usb

i have a project about USB disk.i have achieved eject the usb disk in my code.but then i want to know how to reload it?  Can anyone give me some suggestion.
better an example!thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this question in this way,flow is my code:

win32.cs

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SystemDevices
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SP_BROADCAST_HANDLE
    {
        public int dbch_size;
        public int dbch_devicetype;
        public int dbch_reserved;
        public IntPtr dbch_handle;
        public IntPtr dbch_hdevnotify;
        public Guid dbch_eventguid;
        public long dbch_nameoffset;
        public byte dbch_data;
        public byte dbch_data1;
    }

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
{
    public int dbcc_size;
    public int dbcc_devicetype;
    public int dbcc_reserved;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SP_DEVINFO_DATA
{
    public int cbSize;
    public Guid classGuid;
    public int devInst;
    public IntPtr reserved;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SP_DEVINSTALL_PARAMS
{
    public int cbSize;
    public int Flags;
    public int FlagsEx;
    public IntPtr hwndParent;
    public IntPtr InstallMsgHandler;
    public IntPtr InstallMsgHandlerContext;
    public IntPtr FileQueue;
    public IntPtr ClassInstallReserved;
    public int Reserved;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string DriverPath;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS
{
    public SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER ClassInstallHeader = new SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER();
    public int StateChange;
    public int Scope;
    public int HwProfile;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER
{
    public int cbSize;
    public int InstallFunction;
};

public class Win32
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr RegisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr hRecipient, DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE NotificationFilter, UInt32 Flags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern UInt32 UnregisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr hHandle);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref Guid ClassGuid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String Enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, Int32 Flags);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevsEx(ref Guid ClassGuid,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String Enumerator,
        IntPtr hwndParent, Int32 Flags, IntPtr DeviceInfoSet,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]String MachineName,
        IntPtr Reserved);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Int32 SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(IntPtr lpInfoSet);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(IntPtr lpInfoSet, Int32 dwIndex, SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(IntPtr lpInfoSet, SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, UInt32 Property,
        UInt32 PropertyRegDataType, StringBuilder PropertyBuffer, UInt32 PropertyBufferSize, IntPtr RequiredSize);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS ClassInstallParams, int ClassInstallParamsSize);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiCallClassInstaller(UInt32 InstallFunction, IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiClassNameFromGuid(ref Guid ClassGuid, StringBuilder className, Int32 ClassNameSize, ref Int32 RequiredSize);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiGetClassDescription(ref Guid ClassGuid, StringBuilder classDescription, Int32 ClassDescriptionSize, ref Int32 RequiredSize);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, StringBuilder DeviceInstanceId, Int32 DeviceInstanceIdSize, ref Int32 RequiredSize);

    public const int DIGCF_ALLCLASSES = (0x00000004);
    public const int DIGCF_PRESENT = (0x00000002);
    public const int INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1;
    public const int SPDRP_DEVICEDESC = (0x00000000);
    public const int MAX_DEV_LEN = 200;
    public const int DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE = (0x00000000);
    public const int DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE = (0x00000001);
    public const int DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES = (0x00000004);
    public const int DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = (0x00000005);
    public const int DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED = (0x0007);
    public const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = (0x0219);
    public const int DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE = (0x00000012);
    public const int DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL = (0x00000001);
    public const int DICS_FLAG_CONFIGSPECIFIC = (0x00000002);
    public const int DICS_ENABLE = (0x00000001);
    public const int DICS_DISABLE = (0x00000002);

    public static bool StateChange(bool Enable, int SelectedItem, IntPtr DevInfo)
    {
        bool result = false;
        SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA(); ;
        devInfoData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
        if (true == SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(DevInfo, SelectedItem, devInfoData))
        {
            SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS pcp = new SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS(); ;
            pcp.ClassInstallHeader.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER));
            pcp.ClassInstallHeader.InstallFunction = DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE;
            pcp.Scope = DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL;
            pcp.StateChange = (Enable ? DICS_ENABLE : DICS_DISABLE);
            if (true == SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(DevInfo, devInfoData, pcp, Marshal.SizeOf(pcp)))
            {
                if (true == SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE, DevInfo, devInfoData))
                {
                    result = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String GetClassNameFromGuid(Guid guid)
    {
        String result = String.Empty;
        StringBuilder className = new StringBuilder();
        Int32 iRequiredSize = 0;
        Int32 iSize = 0;
        bool b = SetupDiClassNameFromGuid(ref guid, className, iSize, ref iRequiredSize);

        className = new StringBuilder(iRequiredSize);
        iSize = iRequiredSize;

        b = SetupDiClassNameFromGuid(ref guid, className, iSize, ref iRequiredSize);
        if (true == b)
        {
            result = className.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static String GetClassDescriptionFromGuid(Guid guid)
    {
        String result = String.Empty;
        StringBuilder classDesc = new StringBuilder(0);
        Int32 iRequiredSize = 0;
        Int32 iSize = 0;
        bool b = SetupDiGetClassDescription(ref guid, classDesc, iSize, ref iRequiredSize);

        classDesc = new StringBuilder(iRequiredSize);
        iSize = iRequiredSize;

        b = SetupDiGetClassDescription(ref guid, classDesc, iSize, ref iRequiredSize);
        if (true == b)
        {
            result = classDesc.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String GetDeviceInstanceId(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData)
    {
        String result = String.Empty;
        StringBuilder id = new StringBuilder(0);
        Int32 iRequiredSize = 0;
        Int32 iSize = 0;
        bool b = SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(DeviceInfoSet, DeviceInfoData, id, iSize, ref iRequiredSize);

        id = new StringBuilder(iRequiredSize);
        iSize = iRequiredSize;

        b = SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(DeviceInfoSet, DeviceInfoData, id, iSize, ref iRequiredSize);
        if (true == b)
        {
            result = id.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

in the win32.cs there is some function to control the hardware.

function StateChange(bool Enable, int SelectedItem, IntPtr DevInfo) is used to control the hardware start or stop.
there are three Parameters.when the Enable is true,this function makes the hardware whos id is SelectedItem start,if false stop.i get the id in this code:

```
 Guid classGuid = Guid.Empty;
        IntPtr hDevInfo = Win32.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref classGuid, null, IntPtr.Zero, Win32.DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | Win32.DIGCF_PRESENT);
        if (hDevInfo.ToInt32() == Win32.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("read hardware information error");
        }
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            StringBuilder deviceName = new StringBuilder();
            deviceName.Capacity = Win32.MAX_DEV_LEN;
            do
            {
                SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
                devInfoData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
                devInfoData.classGuid = Guid.Empty;
                devInfoData.devInst = 0;
                devInfoData.reserved = IntPtr.Zero;
                bool result = Win32.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, i, devInfoData);
                if (false == result)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Device: {0}", i);
                Console.WriteLine("\tGuid={0}", devInfoData.classGuid);
                Console.WriteLine("\tName={0}", Win32.GetClassNameFromGuid(devInfoData.classGuid));
                Console.WriteLine("\tDescription={0}", Win32.GetClassDescriptionFromGuid(devInfoData.classGuid));}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

private void btnenable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
const string keyName = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\USBSTOR";

// int tLong = (int )Registry.GetValue(keyName, "Start",0);
Registry.SetValue(keyName, "Start", "00000003");
MessageBox.Show("USB MassStorage Enabled"); 

}

private void btndisable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
const string keyName = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\USBSTOR";

// int tLong = (int )Registry.GetValue(keyName, "Start",0);
Registry.SetValue(keyName, "Start", "00000004");
MessageBox.Show("USB MassStorage Disabled"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool (devcon) available from Microsoft that can be used to achieve the functionality of the device manager.

The following command is used to remove a specific device (Assuming your device name is Kingston)

```
> devcon remove *Kingston*
```

This causes the device to be disabled. So it is no longer available.
The command rescan enables the device.

```
> devcon rescan
```

You can execute this command through the Process.Start() method.
This does not work with devices that have marked for 'Safe Removal'